# Difference between Report server project wizard and Report server project

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am trying to know the differnce between report server project wizard and report server project. i tried google, but was not happie with the answers.

can some one please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

**Report Server Project**:

A Report Server Project is a Business Intelligence Projects template installed by Visual Studio that is available from the New Project dialog box. Report Server project properties apply to all reports and all shared data sources in a project. These properties include the URL for the report server and the folder names for reports and shared data sources.

**Report Server Project Wizard**:

Report Server Wizard Project automatically creates a report server project using Report Wizard. In the wizard, you can create a report by following instructions on each page to create a connection string to a data source, set data source credentials, design a query, add a table or matrix data region, specify report data and groups, pick a font and color style, publish the report to a report server, and preview the report locally.

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ede9b706-4141-4f42-bf4d-199f2286c849/what-is-the-difference-between-report-server-project-wizard-and-report-model-project-and-report?forum=sqlreportingservices

See this thread for your answer.